# Dropdownlist change event not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this piece of code, that just refuses to co-operate, I've tried to look over the syntax, tried .change, .click events, nothing works, I am trying to alert the user, if the function works, nothing.
Heres the Javascript code:

```
$('#ProductNamesList').change(function () {
    alert('JQuery works!');
});
```

And the HTMLHelper that generates the drop down list

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductNamesList", New SelectList(Model.ProductList))
```

Can someone please help? I can't test it in other browsers, due to our requirements here -.-

For the record, I am using jquery-1.6.4.js and jquery-ui-1.8.16.js

Comment: WFM, http://jsbin.com/esojik/2/edit#javascript,html,live Please send URL that reproduces the problem.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/esojik/3/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: give us the link i am on linux (chrome) i may take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ProductNamesList').live('change', function (event) {
     alert('JQuery works!');
 });

});
```

Comment: @Reigo,Can you post the html here ? .I mean the html generated

Comment: @Reigo,Didnt find any problem in your code.and its working perfectly .idk what happens in your case.check the demo .http://jsfiddle.net/cmQsV/

Comment: What the... As soon as I tried the snipet you had there, it worked ??? Realy odd, don't even realy know what was the cause, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code and it works.

```
<form action="">
  <select id="sel">
    <option>AUDI</option>
    <option>Axel</option>
    <option>BCS</option>
    <option>BIBO</option>
   </select>
</form>
<p id=result>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sel").change(function () {
    alert("JQuery works!");
 });
});
```

When I try it at your live demo, I am getting error $ is not defined. I have created a jsfiddle which also works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtFUs/

So all you have to do is to make sure that you are adding jquery correctly and the id of the select box is "mySelectBoxId" and you reference it using #, for example $("#mySelectBoxId"), that's it.

Comment: Tried it with .click, .change event, nothing =/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your live demo, it seems the problem is with the use of `name="#sel"`. The correct notation is `id="sel"`.

If you insist on use of `name` attribute, use jQuery selector `[name="sel"]`. Also note that the hash sign is redundant in attribute value.

Comment: Actually I changed it to "sel" there, made a type-o

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with it, the following worked for me in Firefox and IE8 (don't have IE9 available here).

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductNamesList", new SelectList(Model.ProductList))
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#ProductNamesList').change(function () {
      alert('JQuery works!');
   });
</script>
```

Is the masterpage hooked up properly, and the reference to jquery correct?

Comment: The javascript seems to be missing in there. Once added, it works fine for me though. Also added a fixed version of your jsbin sample at http://jsbin.com/esojik/8/edit#source.